# Make main take full height of body except header NextJS React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a nav element, with the following code:

```js
export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <>
      <header
        className={
          "bg-white flex flex-row justify-between items-center px-20 py-4 filter drop-shadow-md"
        }
      >
      </header>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have a component that is rendered as a sibling of the nav in `_app`:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
        <Nav />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I would like to make `Component` take up the whole page height below the nav. THe nav doesn't have a fixed height, and I don't want to do that.

Comment: could you mention what went wrong right now?

Comment: Right now, the main is taking the width of the children(div with some text)

Comment: @Akash Do you want the component to take the full width or full height? It's unclear because you mention _width_ in the title, but then refer to _height_ in the question.

Comment: @juliomalves ah sorry about that, typed the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some css to fix this.

```
  <SessionProvider>
    <Nav />
    <main>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
    <style jsx>{'
      main {
        width: 100%;
      }
    '}
  </SessionProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, I hope I understand correctly ...
I tried to explain it as best I could. Hope this helps you ;-) Best Greetings and Good Luck!

Create `Layout.js` component with `main` tag and set the `className` to `"w-full"` When You use `Tailwindcss`  if not (width:100%)

```js
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";

function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Nav />
      <main className="w-full">{props.children}</main>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

And wrap <Component {... pageProps} /> into **`_app.js`**

```js
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: it's height not width.. it was a type initially in the question